# Installing font awesome pro version with Angular font-awesome

Tags: angular, npm, font-awesome

I was trying to install the pro version of Angular Font-awesome by first setting up my registry

`npm config set "@fortawesome:registry" https://npm.fontawesome.com/ && \
 npm config set "//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken" TOKEN`

and after that if I try to install the pro version using the following command

```
npm install @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome-pro@<version>
```

then it fails complaining package not found. Is the pro package named something else or does the angular version doesn't support the pro version yet?

Comment: That's because there is no such package exists. https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome same instruction how you would install for pro, they are individual libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit late answer, but what you have done is the correct way. And I guess you replaced TOKEN with your real token right?
You should use this to install the components:

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro
npm install @fortawesome/pro-brands-svg-icons
```